# preg_replace remove html tag issue

Tags: php, preg-replace

It's a very silly mistake what I am doing, actually in my html , I have lots of

```
<li class="MsoNormal" style="margin:0in 0in 0pt">
            <span style="font-family:'Calibri','sans-serif';font-size:11pt">May be required to work extra hours at month end to meet monthly deadlines. .</span>
 </li>
```

I want to replace these all tag like LI, span with - 
so output will be

"- May be required to work extra hours at month end to meet monthly deadlines. ."

I am using this code

```
$a = preg_replace('/(<li[^>]*><span[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/span><\/li>)/imsU',"-$2",$a);
```

But it is not working. Please suggest.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have a line break between `<\/span>` and `<\/li>`

Comment: If I am asking for any help, why someone give it negative marking

Comment: then How will I handle that line break

Comment: Use \s* for 0 or more whitespace characters.

Comment: add `\n` between these closing tags in your regex.

Answer (score 1):

did you try `strip_tags()` ? It's an easy way to do what you want I think ...

Answer (score 0):

You have line breaks that are not present in your regular expression. Especially between tags. Correct regular expression would be:

```
$a = preg_replace('/(<li[^>]*>(?:[\s]*)<span[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/span>(?:[\s]*)<\/li>)/imsU', "-$2", $a);
```

`?:` is here to leave second match still being second. (that's called non-capturing grouping)